# mousedown not working on dynamically loaded element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dynamic, mousedown

I am trying to load my navigation bar like this:

```
$.get("nav.html",function(menuData){
  $("body").html(menuData);
)};
```

and within "nav.html" we have something like

```
<td id='menu-item-1'>menu item 1</td>
<td id='menu-item-2'>menu item 2</td>
```

etc.  So then I want to assign an event to each item and I have tried this:

```
$("#menu-item-1").mousedown(function(response){
  //create an empty table
  $("body").append("table id='menu-item-1-sub-table'></table>");
  //retrieve php data and insert it in the table
  $.get("data.php",function(response){
    $("#menu-item-1-sub-table").html(response);
  });
});
```

The problem is the event will not fire.  It worked when I had the html directly in the javascript, e.g.:

```
$("body").append("<table><tr><td id='menu-item-1'>menu-item-1</td></tr></table>");
```

but upon moving it to another file it no longer works.

EDIT

this was one answer that worked:

use

```
$("body").on('click','#menu-item-1',function(){
etc.
});
```

because menu-item-1 wasn't created yet when we tried

```
$("#menu-item-1).mousedown
```

Comment: Which file has the `$("#menu-item-1").mousedown(...` javascript in it?

Comment: all the javascript is in one file.  Also it is in the order I have posted: the first block is right after document.ready and the third block is right under it, and then document.ready is closed.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In this QA site, when an answer is realized, we do not append "(SOLVED)" to the question title. Instead, we mark a correct answer by clicking on the checkbox to the upper-left of that answer. If you come up with the answer yourself, then post your own answer, give it some time, and if no one has a better answer (your discretion), you can accept your own after a 48-hour wait period.

Comment: Thanks, I had an account a couple years ago, and I remember seeing it at that time.  I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give you an answer replacing

```
$("#menu-item-1").on("click",function(){
  //stuff
});
```

with

```
$('body').on('click','#menu-item-1', function(){
  //stuff
});
```

works because when the `.on()` is delegated `#menu-item-1` isn't on the page yet, but when it is called it can select `#menu-item-1`

Comment: Thanks! I had to restart my account today so again, I just realized, I can't vote (less than 15 reputation).

Comment: Worked well for me. Could you give a little more elaborated explanation. Waiting to vote.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this work with mousedown? ```.on('click'``` isn't having the same effect on the click/unclick feature I got working

Answer (score 0):

your better off appending the table when you get the response rather than appending a table and then setting the html of the appended table

```
$('body').on('click','#menu-item-1', function() {
  $.get("data.php",function(response){
    $("body").append('<table id="menu-item-1-sub-table">'+response+'</table>');
  });
});
```

based upon what you've already done

```
$('body').on('click','#menu-item-1', function() {
  $("body").append("<table id='menu-item-1-sub-table'></table>");
  $.get("data.php",function(response){
    $("#menu-item-1-sub-table").html(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: `.live()` is depreciated and now removed, I was grabbing the [link to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418451/click-event-on-dynamically-generated-list-items-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for the answer; that makes sense, however I should add that the primary goal was to remove the html from the javascript file.

Comment: fair enough, i was typing my code of the top of my head and forgot about that

Comment: @user1993502 what are you trying to suggest? i don't get what you mean?

Comment: Well I am just saying that I don't want to have html in my .js file, at all.  I think it will ultimately be cleaner and easier to edit.

Comment: try replacing `$("#menu-item-1").on("click",` with `$('body').on('click','#menu-item-1',` because when the `.on()` is called `#menu-item-1` isn't on the page yet.

Comment: BeardFist, that worked.  Since you commented I can't vote the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because you must set your handlers inside the get callback after body.html(menuData). But if it all will work, i think it is a weird way to load menu template on page.

Answer (score 0):

you said another file - did you add jquery to that code ? or maybe element doesnt exist when you load mousedown code - try jquery on-function.

```
 $('#menuitem').on(function(){

    $("#menu-item-1").mousedown(function(response){
      $("body").append("table id='menu-item-1-sub-table'></table>");
       $.get("data.php",function(response){
       $("#menu-item-1-sub-table").html(response);
       })
     });
   })
```

Comment: I checked with developer tools in chrome and the elements exist with their respective id's.  Tried the .on but it also didn't work.  Thanks though