# Click event on dynamically generated list items using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

I have a list being dynamically generated and then I click on the item and pass the `index()` to another function.

The problem is that this list is being populated dynamically and my code does not respond when I do `click` event. BUT, if I add a couple of Static li elements to the list in addition to the dynamically populated ones those Static ones work. Its very odd.

Some code:

This dynamically creates the list:

```
function SetOpenRecentURL( openRecentURL ) {

 $('#recentProjectsId').append('<li>' + openRecentURL + '</li>')
 }
```

This is the click event to pass the Index():

```
$('#recentProjectsId li').on('click', function () {
        var projIndex = $(this).index();
        console.log(projIndex)
        OpenProject()

    })
```

The HTML with a few Static Li's

```
<div class="recentProjects" id="recentProjectsId">
<li>Test 1</li>
<li>Test 2</li>
        </div>
```

When I run my program my list looks perfect and includes my static li plus my dynamic ones, but I cannot click on the dynamic ones, only static.

Comment: Your markup is not valid, since `<li>` elements can't have `<div>` parent.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> When I run my program my list looks perfect and includes my static li plus my dynamic ones, but I cannot click on the dynamic ones, only static.

That's because, the way your code binds the `click` handler, it is only bound to elements in the page at the time that the the listener is bound. Set up the click listener [just a little differently](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and it will work, by taking advantage of event delegation:

```
$('#recentProjectsId').on('click', 'li', function () {
    // snip...
});
```

By specifying an additional `selector` argument to `.on()`:

> A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

---

Note that your HTML is currently invalid. [`<li>` elements are only valid inside of `<ul>`s, `<ol>`s, and `<menu>`s.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element)

Comment: Worked perfectly! I thought `.on()` instead of `.click()` was taking care of it for me, i guess not. Thanks for the help

Comment: You were very close. Using `.on()` got you 95% of the way there.

Comment: Works like a cham

Answer (score 1):

You may use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#recentProjectsId").on("click", "li", function() {
    var projIndex = $(this).index();
    console.log(projIndex)
    OpenProject()
});
```

Here `#recentProjectsId` is the parent element of `<li>`.