# jQuery on 'click' on a dynamic generated list returns 'an empty string'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a input list with this function:

```
function buildHTMLinputfields(data, form_id){
    var row$ = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){        
        row$ = " <label for='check1'>" + data[i].Attribute_Name + "<input data-guid='" + data[i].GUID + "' type='checkbox' name='" + data[i].Name + "' value='" + data[i].Name + "' id='check1' checked='checked'> " + data[i].Name + " </label><br>";

        $(form_id).append(row$);
    }
}
```

Output on my website:

```html
        <label for="check1">
        Adressierung
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="check1" value="volladressierbar" name="volladressierbar" data-guid="17caabea-c313-48c9-b965-739ef8d09a1f"> volladressierbar
        </label><br>
        
        <label for="check1">
        Adressierung
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="check1" value="teiladressierbar" name="teiladressierbar" data-guid="d4419b55-3bb1-4efd-8f1c-f2ae3ed46988"> teiladressierbar
        </label><br>
        
        <label for="check1">
        Empfänger
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="check1" value="privat" name="privat" data-guid="c14733e5-64f1-4141-a366-a9fd5dfa0aff"> privat
        </label><br>
        
        <label for="check1">Empfänger<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="check1" value="Gewerbe" name="Gewerbe" data-guid="6febb58c-8c1d-4f84-a647-5409107c2002"> Gewerbe
        </label><br>
```

So good... I've some input checkboxen.

Now I want to get a alert or console.log output if I click on one checkbox.

This is my function for it (**Here is the problem I think**):

```
function test(){
    $('body').on('click', 'input', function(){
        var text = '';
        text = $('#check1').text(); // empty???
        console.log(text); // Output -> (an empty string)
    });
}
```

The console says me: *(an empty string)*

I search a whole time in Google and SO but I can't find my issue.

I try this (without success):

[Click event on dynamically generated list items using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418451/click-event-on-dynamically-generated-list-items-using-jquery)

**For your information (I think it is important) - I initialize the functions here:**

```
function ip_get_order_filters(){
    var cookie_value_bearer = getCookie('ip_token');

    var setHeader = function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', "Bearer " + cookie_value_bearer);
    };    

    $.ajax({
        crossdomain: true,
        url: 'https://testapi.***.de/***',
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        beforeSend: setHeader,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { 
            buildHTMLinputfields(data, '#filterform'); //generate the input list
            test();
        }        
    });    
}
```

Comment: You're having multiple elements with `id="check1"` in your HTML. `id` attribute is meant to be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `val` instead of `text` and `id` must be unique. You can do it like following without concern of `id` using `this`.

```
 $('body').on('click', 'input', function(){
    var text = '';
    text = $(this).val(); 
    console.log(text); 
});
```