# $(this).addClass is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

While following a tutorial, I see style sheet is not applied to clicked  element in the list. What Could be the possible reason?

The following sample works this way if some string is added to text box and then button is clicked, a new item gets added to list. If item in the list is clicked it should be stroked through.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#taskText').keydown(function (evt) {  
                if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                    addTask(this, evt);
                }
            });

            $('#addTask').click(function (evt) {
                addTask(document.getElementById('taskText'), evt);
            });

            // following statements not working 

            $('#tasks li').live('click', function(evt) {
                $(this).addClass('done');

            });});

        function addTask(textBox, evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var taskText = textBox.value;
            $('<li>').text(taskText).appendTo('#tasks'); 
            textBox.value = "";
        };
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .done{
            text-decoration:line-through;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <ul id="tasks">
   </ul>
    <input type="text" id="taskText" />
    <input type="submit" id="addTask"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try change  `$('#tasks li').live('click', function(evt) {
                $(this).addClass('done');
            });});` to  `$('#tasks li').on('click', function(evt) {
                $(this).addClass('done');
            });});`

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding.Tried but sadly , it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#addTask').click(function() {
     var taskText = $('#taskText').val();
     var li = $('<li>' + taskText + '</li>');
     $('ul#tasks').append(li);
     $('#taskText').val('');
     $(li).click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass('done');
     });
   });
 });
```

```css
li {
  font-family: arial;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.done{
   text-decoration: line-through;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
</head>    
<body>
  <ul id="tasks">
    <!-- List Goes Here... -->
  </ul>

  <!-- Textbox / Input Buttons -->  
   <input type="text" id="taskText" />
   <input type="submit" id="addTask"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried the suggested one, but sadly it did not work.

Comment: Try second one and if this still doesn't works. then if you don't mind can you example of your code in codepen.io ?

Comment: Please find it here.

Comment: Thanks Sam It works perfectly fine, what could be the possible reason that we have to add default element in the list and this default one is not getting stroked through?

Comment: There is no reason to add default one, I just wrote it for no reason.
The program will still work fine even if its removed.

Comment: If you want default one to get stoked through as well, Then you need to add another event listener for that. Then both will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The [`live()` function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in jQuery 1.7 and does not exist at all in jQuery 2.x.

If you check your browser's developer console, chances are you'll see an error message along those lines.

Comment: Thanks for responding.Any alternative to that?

Comment: @Chanchal First line of that documentation link is "Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: This has been marked as best answer? Did your problem solved @chanchal ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#tasks li').click(function(){
     $(this).addClass('class-name');
};
```

should work. Check to make sure all your syntax is correct (ie. no random semicolons)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by ceejayoz . The [`live()` function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) was removed in jQuery 1.7 and does not exist at all in jQuery 2.x.

The reason your click on the list was not working is better explained on this question: [Click event on dynamically generated list items using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418451/)

here's what the code could look like for you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#taskText').keydown(function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
      addTask(this, evt);
    }
  });

  $('#addTask').click(function(evt) {
    addTask($('#taskText'), evt);
  });


  $('#tasks').on('click', 'li', function(evt) {
    $(this).addClass('done');
  });
});

function addTask(textBox, evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var taskText = textBox.val();
  $('<li>').text(taskText).appendTo('#tasks');
  textBox.val("");
};
```

```css
.done {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="tasks">
</ul>
<input type="text" id="taskText" />
<input type="submit" id="addTask" />
```