# create clickable list in html

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists

```
<ul id="add-message"></ul>

document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = () => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#message').value;
  document.querySelector('#add-message').append(li);       
};

<form>
  <input type="text" id="message">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

problem is that this can create dynamic list but i like to make it clickable 
so that i create popup input by click on list element .

i need something like this

```
 <div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active">
    Cras justo odio
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action disabled">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

show that user can see it is clickable , so how to add dynamically href and class attribute

Comment: Why don't you attach a click event on `li` ?

Comment: you can adopt https://stackoverflow.com/q/14418451/3953479 , as per your need

Answer (score 1):

You can add click event to the newly created `li`. Since the button is of type submit, you also have to prevent the default event (`event.preventDefault()`) to stay on the page:

```js
document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = (event)=>{
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log('You have clicked: ',this.textContent);
  });
  li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#message').value;
  document.querySelector('#add-message').append(li);  
  event.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<ul id="add-message">

</ul>



<form>
  <input type="text" id="message">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onclick` on `li` before append to `dom`.

```
<ul id="add-message">

 </ul>


document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = ()=>{
const li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#message').value;
li.onclick = function(){
console.log("clicked");
}
document.querySelector('#add-message').append(li);       

};

<form>
<input type="text" id="message">
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default behavior of the  `input type = submit`  & then use `event.target` to get the content from the `li` on click

```js
document.querySelector("#submit").onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#message').value;
  document.querySelector('#add-message').append(li);
};

document.querySelector("#add-message").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(e.target.innerHTML)

})
```

```html
<ul id="add-message">

</ul>

<form>
  <input type="text" id="message">
  <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```