# Get the value of a cell in a dynamically generated table with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Link code below basically I'm populating a table with recipe ingredients from a json file.  I want to be able to click on a individual ingredient and display the description on a div below.  Tried just targeting td elements without using a class tried wrapping them in anchor tags as well as building html on click on each cell when it was created,

```
                if (data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient' + i] !== null) {
                    $("#recipe").append($('<tr>'))
                    $("#recipe").append($('<td class ="ingredient"></td>').html(data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient' + i]).val(data['drinks'][0]['strIngredient' + i]));
                    $("#recipe").append($('<td></td>').html(data['drinks'][0]['strMeasure' + i]));
                    $("#recipe").append($('</tr>'));
                    i++;
                } else iCheck = true;
            }

                 $(".ingredient").click(function () {
                      console.log('fired')
                  })


<div id="drinkDescription">
    <p id="name" name="name"></p>
    <br>
    <table id="recipe" name="recipe">

    </table>
    <br>
    <p id="description" name="description">

    </p>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we see HTML code as well. Perhaps you could create a snippet? What have you tried so far?

Comment: what's the issue? click event is not firing or it is firing, but not sure how to get data from cell?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click event on dynamically generated list items using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418451/click-event-on-dynamically-generated-list-items-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you are having is when you add an event handler it attaches to the elements that are available at that point.

What you want to do is use event delegation so it will attach to future items.

```
$("#recipe").on("click",".ingredient",function () {
```