# Jquery mousedown not firing on datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, mousedown

Honestly flummoxed.  This works when I fire it on the random `div` to log 'fun' to the console, but, if I change it to `.select-checkbox` or `td` I get no response.

The `td` cell in question does include a `:before` and an `:after` to render a checkbox-like-checkbox, so maybe there's some weird interference there...

```
    $('td.select-checkbox').mousedown(function(){
        console.log('fun')
     });
```

Alternatively, though I have trouble believing and/or googling this, the [JQuery Docs](https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) seem to state that mousedown only works on divs... like maybe actual `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the table cells are dynamically loaded and therefore the handler is not registered on page load correctly. In which case you can register it on 'body' instead:

[mousedown not working on dynamically loaded element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14418401/mousedown-not-working-on-dynamically-loaded-element)